# Fixed media player

Tags: html, css, media

The following website has a fixed media player at the top of the page. When you click internal links and browse through the site, the audio feed is uninterrupted.

http://www.kcrw.com/music/shows/eclectic24

What technique are they using? A fixed iFrame? Or is it just a simple DIV and the rest of the page(s) are loaded dynamically in a way that I do not understand?

Answer (score 2):

It is a DIV.  Have a look at the source code of the page and you will see

```
  <div id="big_player" class="prevent-selection">
          <div id="big_player_progress">
            <div class="indicator">
              <div class="progress-gradient"></div>
  <snip snip>
```

Comment: ...and the page does not "reload" completely as the user navigates around. Content is loaded dynamaically via AJAX (XMLHttpRequest object) and HTML5 pushState (history object) allows the URL to be updated dynamically.